# Which one is better regarding the proper use of "respectively"?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

Which one sounds better regarding the proper use of "respectively"?

a) The *x* and *y* are connected to *g* and *h* in the designed network respectively.

b) The *x* and *y* are connected to *g* and *h* respectively in the designed network.

c) The *x* and *y* are connected respectively to *g* and *h* in the designed network.

Comment: Why refer to "the " x but just g?  I'd go with b) but drop the "the"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference, really. The standard usage is to put the "respectively" at the end of sentence because that's typically where the comparison ends, but you **do** need a comma as it is an adverbial modifier if you decide to leave it at said end; moreover, being an adverb and having its meaning work in any order, you can leave it wherever you like. I must mention, however, that it is more logical to put respectively after you mention "g and h", not in between. This is more of a stylistic issue at this point.

From doing a "define respectively" or just typing it in Google, one will find this example under Google's given definition: "they received sentences of one year and eight months, respectively".